# execute command from console using symfony

Tags: symfony1, console

I'm learning to use Symfony and I didn't understand how use console command...I'm using MAMP installed in Lion OS X 10.7. Suppose I would create a controller

```
php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/HelloBundle --format=yml
```

like this. From where I have to execute this command ? I mean when I start console where do I have to put the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be in your project directory. Do you get some errors ?